# JavaScript Objects: Dynamically handling an accessor?

Tags: javascript, v8, accessor

How do I check to see which object is being accessed, effectively creating a dynamic setter?

I want to do something like this:

```
var People = {};
// ...some code to change accessor on People...
var greeting = People.StevenSpielberg;
alert(greeting); // "Hi StevenSpielberg!"
```

And the *pseudocode* I might write would be:

```
People[name] = function(name) { return "Hi " + name; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: What you're asking for requires a not-yet-standardized feature of the JavaScript language.

Comment: StevenSpielberg is undefined on People. I want a getter function that can read the accessed item as a string so I can do something in the getter with that item. Does that make sense?

Comment: You want to see that it was undefined, and behind the scenes automatically set a value based on the name of the attribute trying to be accessed?

Comment: @Pointy It's like the Object.defineProperty except the getter should take an input. Does that make sense? Are you sure?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @batman for that you'd want the proposed ES6 "proxy" feature I think.

Comment: @Pointy haven't seen that, thanks -- now to find the interim implementation ;)